# How would I insert records into excel file for MS access application?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, recordset

I have a MS Access application that would allow users to search for records of doctors and insert records of new doctors. The application uses an excel file to store the records of doctors. I created a button on a form called "InsertBtn" that when clicked should insert a record of a new doctors.

However, the code I have for the VBA script doesn't work. Every time I click the button it says there is an error in the Insert SQL statement

```
Private Sub InsertBtn_Click()
    
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO employeelist (Last Name, First Name, Facility, Specialty, Office #, Fax #, Cell #, address 1, Street address, City, State, Zip Code, Email, WebPage) VALUES('" & Me.LastNameInsert.Value & "', '" & Me.FirstNameInsert.Value & "', N/A, '" & Me.SpecialtyInsert.Value & "', N/A, N/A, '" & Me.CellNumInsert.Value & "', N/A, N/A, '" & Me.CityInsert.Value & "', N/A, N/A, N/A, N/A')"

End Sub
```

I've tried playing around with different MS access functions. I tried currentdb.execute and then tried docmd.runsql. I included all the column fields of the excel file in the sql statement. I think the error might lie in the values part of the sql statement.

Comment: Check these column names 'Fax #', 'Office #', 'Address 1', 'Zip Code', etc. You can't use them in this form without enclosing them in something (because they have special characters in them); try using square brackets or double quotes around each.

Comment: Also, the spaces are an issue. Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention. Access requires `[ ]` as object delimiters: `[Zip Code]`. Better would be `OfficeNum`, `ZipCode` - no brackets necessary.

Comment: I changed the column names, but ms access says this is still not working. 
                                                                                                                
My code:                                                                                                  
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO doctorlist(LastName, FirstName, Facility, Specialty, Office, Fax, Cell, address, StreetAddress, City, State, ZipCode, Email, WebPage) VALUES("a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a)"

Answer (score 1):

*Values* cannot be a long string:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO employeelist ([Last Name], [First Name], [Facility], [Specialty], [Office #], [Fax #], [Cell #], [address 1], [Street address], [City], [State], [Zip Code], [Email], [WebPage]) VALUES('" & Me.LastNameInsert.Value & "', '" & Me.FirstNameInsert.Value & "', 'N/A', '" & Me.SpecialtyInsert.Value & "', 'N/A', 'N/A', " & Me.CellNumInsert.Value & ", 'N/A', 'N/A', '" & Me.CityInsert.Value & "', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A')"
```

Also, if you cannot insert `'N/A'` in a numeric field, try with `Null` (with no quotes).